# Applications for the tail bounds for the hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, applications, hypergeometric-function

I am interested in the applications for the probability tail bounds (non-asymptotic) for the hypergeometric distribution. I would be very appreciative if you can name or link me to some.

Comment: By 'bounds' you mean as $n \to \infty$, i.e. as the pool size grows infinitely large?

Comment: did you try this? https://www.google.ca/search?q=bounds+on+hypergeometric+distribution&oq=bounds+on+hypergeometric+distribution&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62l2.9660&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Sorry, I did not mentioned, I am interested i the non-asymptotic bounds.

Comment: Did you find anything useful in the Google results?

Comment: Unfortunately, not...